# "dynlib/dll was no found when the application was frozen" when I make a .exe file using pyinstaller, because of pylibmtx the error was occurred

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

[image]

when I [image]

I am struggling to make .exe files.
the error message was shown that it has problem on number 9 line, so I checked my code. there were imported library "pylibdmtx" which is to decode the datamatrix.

so I tried to remove all about that library with other related attributes and then it was fine.
I tried to figure that issue out for troubleshooting, but I couldn't find it. so I finally ask my issue to you.

I uploaded captures of my problem

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe little late, but I'll share this information is anyone else has issue with this:

found [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1609).

In the bootloader we call SetDllDirectory with our extraction path. For some reason this seems to prevent loading a dll from the current directory.
If SetDllDirectory is called with a Null argument to reset the dll search path loading a dll from the current directory works.

Example based on vlc and the libvlc.dll.

Doesn't work:

```
import ctypes
import os

os.chdir('C:\\Program Files\\VideoLan\\VLC\\')
print(ctypes.CDLL('libvlc.dll'))
```

Works:

```
import ctypes
import os

ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetDllDirectoryW(None)

os.chdir('C:\\Program Files\\VideoLan\\VLC\\')
print(ctypes.CDLL('libvlc.dll'))
```

So if your code loads external DLL files with ctypes, make sure to add this line before you load your DLL (tested under Windows, not sure about other OSes)

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetDllDirectoryW(None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Freezers such as pyinstaller and cx_Freeze are not able to find libraries loaded using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html). pylibdmtx exposes these binary dependencies in `pylibdmtx.EXTERNAL_DEPENDENCIES` - a list of instances of [ctypes.CDLL](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL). You can get pyinstaller to include these in the freeze using a pyinstaller spec file ([example](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/inselect/blob/196a3ae2a0ed4e2c7cb667aaba9a6be1bcd90ca6/inselect.spec#L35)).

Answer (score 1):

You might have to explicitly include needed the DLL files when creating the executable with Pyinstaller. Assuming the required DLL file is `xyz.dll`, and the python script is `myscript.py`, you can include the DLL like this:

```
> pyinstaller --add-binary xzy.dll;. --onefile myscript.py
```

This places the DLL in the base path within the created executable file

Answer (score 1):

It's late , but I must say what fixed a problem that took 3 days to solve,
simply installing [c++ redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and restart machine solved my probelm

Answer (score 1):

A quick note for that is you might need to add whole address of dll file in some cases.

```
> pyinstaller --add-binary "--add-binary "C:\Users\User\…\xzy.dll;." --onefile myscript.py
```

Comment: Because there are too many pending edits I am commenting. Correct format is 
pyinstaller --add-binary "C:\Users\User\…\xzy.dll:." --onefile myscript.py

Answer (score 0):

Bundle the relevant version of MCVCP*.DLL with your program to satisfy the needs of that DLL in question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, but it was with torchaudio , I fixed this problem by **installing the last version of Visual C++** .

You can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)