# Incompatibility pyinstaller and sklearn

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a .exe file com a .py file using auto-py-to-exe, that uses pyinstaller for creating the file.

The problem is, on codes that I import the sklearn lib, I get the following error on opening the output exe file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhWVi.jpg)

I have already tried including hidden imports from sklearn, cx-freeze, sklearn.neighbors.typedefs','sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree','sklearn.tree._utils' and sklearn.utils._cython_blas.
Also tried one file and one directory, both with same problem.

Also tried directly using pyinstaller, with same error. It works fine on codes without sklearn. Tried on python versions 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8.

Does anyone have a glue on how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: where is img? missing?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54845210/5510499 and https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/27

Comment: Already tried cx_Freeze with no success