# Failed to load dynlib/dll libiconv.dll

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, hidden

when I try to convert python code to exe I get this error (pyimod03_ctypes.install..PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\Users\khale\AppData\Local\Temp\ _MEI76242\pyzbar\libiconv.dll'. Most likely this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen)

I tried putting the specific dll in the dist directory but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dynlib/dll was no found when the application was frozen" when I make a .exe file using pyinstaller, because of pylibmtx the error was occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110504/dynlib-dll-was-no-found-when-the-application-was-frozen-when-i-make-a-exe-fil)